# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Categorize' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/IRIS/controllers/get_category.php:7

Tags: php, xml, class, variables, static-variables

1.
          In the class below called Get_category, I am trying to access an array variable called $arr from another class called Categorize. But everytime I run my Get_category class, an error shows up(the one in the title) saying that it doesn't recognize the Categorize class.

```
class Get_category extends Controller{
     function run($xml){
         global $FILE_ROOT, $STORAGE, $REQ_ID, $CMD_EXTRA, $LIB, $BIN;

         $file = $xml->filename;
         Categorize::$arr;
         $arrlength = count($arr);
         $response = "<parameters>\n<requestID>" . $REQ_ID ."</requestID>\n<requestType>get_category</requestType>";

         for($i = 0; $i < $arrlength; $i++){
         $lengthcolumn = count($arr[$i]);
            for($j = 0; $j < $lengthcolumn; $j++){
                if($arr[$i][$j] == $file){
                    echo $arr[$i][$j];
                    $response .= "<resource><id>" . $arr[$i][$j] . "</id>";
                    $response .= "</resource>";
                }

            }

         }

        $response .= "</parameters>";

        return $response; 


    }    
}
```

This is the other class Categorize that I am trying to access the variable from.

```
    class Categorize extends Controller{
       function run($xml){
              global $FILE_ROOT, $STORAGE, $REQ_ID, $CMD_EXTRA, $LIB, $BIN;


              $numCategories = intval($xml->numCategories);
              static $arr = array();
              /*self::$arr = array();*/

              /*if(!pe($xml, "resourceList")) die(err("No resources found"));*/

              for($i=0;$i < $numCategories; $i++){
                  $name = intval($xml->nameCat);
                         if($i=0){
                            $arr[0][0] = $name;
                         }else{
                            $arr[$i][0] = $name;
                         }

              }
              $j = 0;
              while($j < $numCategories){
                  $numDoc = intval($xml->numDoc);
                       $k = 0;
                       foreach($xml->resourceList->resource as $res){
                                  $arr[$j][$k] = $res;
                                  $k++;
                       }
                   $j++;         
              }
             $output = "Done!";
             $response = "<parameters><requestType>categorize</requestType><requestID>". $REQ_ID . "</requestID><resourceList>". $output . "</resourceList></parameters>";

             return $response;
       }
}
```

For some reason I keep getting the error listed in the title and I don't know why? I have been trying to make my $arr variable static and I have been using the proper notation to get my static variable. It says that it doesn't recognize Categorize in get_Category, so I don't know how to fix it so that it realizes that I am trying to access a class outside of the current one. Could there be a problem with my Categorize class itself?

Comment: Your `$arr` variable is inside a function in the `Categorize` class, therefor its scope is limited to that function. It needs to be moved out into the class encapsulation. Additionally, you need to instantiate the `Categorize` class in `Get_category` class in order to access variable from it.

Answer (score 0):

include the file where the class `Categorize` is imported at to top of the file like this:

```
include_once 'path/to/Categorizeclass'
```

for example at the top of `controllers/get_category.php` add this :

```
include_once __DIR__.'/categorize.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP needs help knowing where it can find the classes you are trying to load, unless they are in the same file, or an included or required file. The function `spl_autoload_register()` is used to provide a function that PHP can use to figure this out.

For example if you have your classes neatly placed in individual files, `Categorize.class.php`and `Get_Category.class.php`, and they are placed in a folder `/classes`, you would use something like this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    require_once(sprintf("/classes/%s.class.php", $class)); 
}
```

This will give PHP an anonymous function that PHP can give the unknown class' name, so you can call the `require` or `include` function yourself, since you know about your folder structures.